# What is Guru parampara of Varkari sect

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism

Varkari sect is Vaishnava community in Maharashtra which serves Panduranga(incarnation of Shri hari) in Pandharpur.

Since every Vaishnava tradition traces its Guru parampara back to Shriman Narayana, what is varkari guruparampara.